# Powershell list all files by relative path with comma separation

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

With PowerShell I try to have a list of file with relative path separeted with commas.

Right now here is my command

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Attributes !D | Group-Object -Property Directory | %{ Write-Host $_.Group }
```

I have no idea on how to output the relative path & filename with comma for each group.

Imagine we are in this folder:

```
PS C:\Work\>
```

This folder contains the following folders and files

```
Folder1\doc1.txt
Folder1\doc2.txt
Folder2\img1.jpg
Folder2\img2.jpg
Folder2\img3.jpg
```

I would like to have this output:

```
Folder1\doc1.txt;Folder1\doc2.txt
Folder2\img1.jpg;Folder2\img2.jpg;Folder2\img3.jpg
```

Comment: Could you show example of desired output?

Comment: @PetSerAl, I've update the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Resolve-Path -Relative` command to get relative path. And for joining you can use `-join` operator:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
Group-Object -Property Directory |
ForEach-Object {
    @(
        $_.Group |
        Resolve-Path -Relative |   # make relative path
        ForEach-Object Substring 2 # cut '.\' part
    )-join';'
}
```